# javascript dynamic variable name with canvas

Tags: javascript, variables, canvas, dynamic

I have looked at the other examples that show to put the variable name in an array. When I do this the loop in my function throws an error.

I am trying to load images for a canvas, each iteration of player should produce the same image format with different variables such as helmets, weapons gloves, ect.

The variable that I am trying to make dynamic is pic, i have tried using `var pic = [];` above the first `for` loop and then to every call I used `pic[i] = new Image(); pic[i].src = ...` and on...
I get the error when I use the variable in the third `for` loop

```
for(var iii = 0, pic[i]; pic[i] = pics[iii++];) {
   ctx.drawImage(pic, 60, 270);
```

It errors out on the first `pic[i]` in the third `for` call

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Here is the code

```
        // For every player run iteration
        var pic = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
            // Position for players on account screen
            if(i == 0){ var pos = "61px";}
            if(i == 1){ var pos = "168px";}
            if(i == 2){ var pos = "275px";}

            // Gets player name from string
            var player = item[i].match( /([A-Z])\w+/g );

            // Create player div for mouse interaction
            var player_el = $('<div class="cursor player" id="player'+ player +'"></div>');
            $("#can_wrapper").append(player_el);
            $("#player"+ player).css({"position": "absolute", "height": "50px", "width": "50px", "left": ""+ pos +"", "top": "271px", "cursor": "grab", "cursor": "-webkit-grab"});

            // Get player name for hover action
            var player_name_el = player;
            document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#player'+ player +':hover::after','content: "'+player_name_el+'";');

            // Player image URLs
            var urls = ['v1456.png', 'vbody0.png','vhead14.png','v1960.png','v578.png','v1221.png', 'v3063.png']; // url and order
            var pics = [];                            // holds the image elements                 
            var count = urls.length;                  // number of images to load

            // For every image run iteration
            for(var ii = 0, url; url = urls[ii++];) {   // share onload handler
                pic[i] = new Image();                // create a new image
                pics.push(pic);                       // store in array
                pic[i].onload = loadCounter;             // set load handler (also add for error)
                pic[i].src = 'https://www.example.com/interface/images/body/' + url; // set url to start loading
            }

            // Load images in the order they were called
            function loadCounter() {
                count--;
                if (!count) {                         // when done we can draw the images in order:
                    for(var iii = 0, pic[i]; pic[i] = pics[iii++];) {
                        ctx.drawImage(pic[i], 60, 270);
                    }
                }
            };

        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `pic[i]` after `var i = 0`

Comment: `var pic[i]` makes no sense. You don't declare array elements.

Comment: the `var pic[i]` was an error in my post sorry, its not actually that way in my code